# Как изменить ключи массива по возрастанию

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

**Нужно вывести список фотографий ссылками последовательно 1 2 3 4 5**, при условии что могут быть отображены не все фотографии, а лишь часть или совсем ничего. Для каждой фотографии в БД есть своя запись ссылки.

```
<?php
        // Создаем отдельный массив со всеми 5 полями фотографий(пустыми и заполненными)
        $array_of_photo = array($showUser['photo1'], $showUser['photo2'], $showUser['photo3'], $showUser['photo4'], $showUser['photo5']);
        // Убираем из массива $array_of_photo все пустые поля, создаем массив с имеющимися фотографиями
        $photos = array_filter($array_of_photo);
        // Проходим цыклом по оставшимся фотографиям и если находим хотя бы одну фотографию, то отображаем "Фотографии:"
        if (!empty($photos)){

            echo "Фотографии: ";

            foreach($photos as $key=>$photo)
            {
                echo " <a href='$photo'>", $key, "</a> ";
            }
        }
?>
```

Проблема в том что список выводится по ключам массива $photos, который может иметь разные ключи в зависимости от того какие поля заполнены в БД, например Array ( [0] => images.jpg [2] => images.jpg [4] => images.jpg )
и соответственно выводятся ссылки в порядке **0 2 4**.

Подскажите как вывести список 1 2 3 . .
Я думаю в сторону изменить значения ключей массива, но возможно все проще и можно вывести циклом, но я учусь и решаю эту задачу уже больше суток.

Comment: Можно вне цикла добавить счётчик, а в цикле его увеличивать ну и соответственно использовать. Вне цикла `$i = 0` в цикле `$i++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое - введите счетчик `$key`, не связанный с массивом `$photos`:

```
$key = 1;
foreach($photos as $photo)
{
    echo " <a href='$photo'>", $key, "</a> ";
    $key++;
}
```